# Open specific jupyter notebook from terminal

Tags: terminal, jupyter

Is it possible to open a specific Jupiter notebook from terminal.
The file -> open -> search for it is time consuming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the server is running, you can open using this url

http(s)://server:port//lab/tree/path/to/notebook.ipynb

https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/urls.html#url-combine

Answer (score 0):

This may depend how what operating system you are using (or environment such as anaconda), but in general I think this should work:

```
jupyter notebook notebook.ipynb
```

...where `notebook.ipynb` is the notebook you want to open, see [here](https://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/running.html#how-do-i-open-a-specific-notebook).

Comment: This will most likely open a new instance of Jupyter. Is it possible to open the open on the current running instance of jupyter notebook?